# What kind of Visa (Russian Federation) do I need?

Tags: visas, transit, russia

I'm traveling to Amsterdam and I have a valid Schengen Multi-Entry Visa. I have a layover in Moscow for 13 Hours and I want to explore the city during that time. Can anyone guide me what kind of Visa should I apply for whether a Transit Visa would be enough or I need to apply for Tourist Visa to VFS-Russia? I am an Indian Citizen. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Comment: 13 hours for moscow is not enough time and keep in mind that you have go through Immigration etc.. That will be touch and go in stress.

Comment: @NRandhawa Yes it is. I visit Moscow at least once in a year. 8 hours layover is enough for 3-4 hours in the city.

Comment: NRandhawa and @Neusser, please stop with this conversation. Both of you have made your point in the comments I have left. The tone of the ones I deleted was not as we want on this site.

Comment: Guys i just want to know should I apply for a regular tourist visa or a transit visa? The time management part is something I can handle.